# import a method from a webpack-ed js file?

Tags: webpack

I have a vendor.js and app.js which were compiled by webpack. I want to use a `api_call` method that lives in `utilities.jsx` from the Chrome/Firefox JS console. How do I make it available on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`expose-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) and also export `api_call` method in `utilities.jsx`.

If `api_call` is exported via `module.exports` then you can make it global with the following configuration:

```
[
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: require.resolve("./src/utilities"),
        loader: "expose?api_call"
      }
    ]
  }
]

// api_call is now available in the global scope
```

If `api_call` is exported via a property of `exports` object:

```
[
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: require.resolve("./src/utilities"),
        loader: "expose?utilities"
      }
    ]
  }
]

// api_call is now available in the global scope through utilities['api_call']
```